# How open start with tab Call Log in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I call a Action_Dial as:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

It show screen with 4 tab : Phone, Call Log, Contacts, Favorites.
But It open start with tab Phone.
I want start with tab Call Log.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
context.startActivity(showCallLog);
```

It will open Call Log Screen.

Comment: how to start calllog activity to pick contact from calllog?

Answer (score 2):

try below code to open Call Log screen directly via intent...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls");
startActivity(intent);
```